# Why does awk function only return last line from file?

Tags: unix, awk

I am using awk to reformat some fields in a file and an awk function to fix one field value if it is negative.  Here is my awk command:

```
awk 'function fix_neg(value) {\
if(value < 0)\
return '$new_value'\
else\
return value\
} END { print $2,$1,fix_neg($3) }' input_file.txt
```

where $new_value was set before this call.  I do not understand why this only returns the reformatted last line of input_file.txt (which contains multiple lines of data).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unless perhaps you're using a C shell derivative, the backslashes are unnecessary.  The shell knows that the single-quote string continues because it hasn't seen the second single quote yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -v newV="$new_value" '{print $2,$1,($3<0?newV:$3)}' inputfile
```

In your program, you only got the last line data because you put your print statement in the `END{..}` block. It is triggered after the whole file was processed, not for each line.  Drop the `END` and it would work as you intended.